# Image's menu doesnt open on left click in XP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am trying to have a image (in WPF) that shows a menu when the mouse is left clicked. It works fine in 7, however, when I try to use it in XP it only shows up when its right clicked? any ideas?

Here is the XAML Code:

```
<Image x:Name="buttonHelp" Width="32" Height="32"  Margin="0,0,5,0" Source="/Little Registry Optimizer;component/Resources/Help.png" MouseEnter="button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="button_MouseLeave" MouseDown="buttonHelp_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

Here is the C# Code:

```
private void button_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void button_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}

private void buttonHelp_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    this.buttonHelp.ContextMenu = contextMenu;

    contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(Properties.Resources.Help, "Help"));
    contextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());
    contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(Properties.Resources.internet, "Visit Website"));
    contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(Properties.Resources.update, "Check for updates"));
    contextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());
    contextMenu.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(Properties.Resources.optimizer, "About..."));

    contextMenu.PlacementTarget = (System.Windows.UIElement)sender;
    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    contextMenu.StaysOpen = true;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure (you should have recognized) but under XP your mouse is NOT configured for left-hand-usage?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your MouseLeftButtonDown event does it get hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you know I have solved this problem by using a button instead of an Image. You can still set the button to have the Image as its content. Then you can simply subscribe to the Buttons Click event (which I know will work on XP or anything else).

One other thing I did was set the placement of the Context Menu with this code:

```
buttonHelp.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
ContextMenuService.SetPlacement(buttonHelp, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom);
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to a button and changed the control template so it displays an image (w/o any borders or anything) and it works fine. Here is the code: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lrc-team/lilregdefrag/devel-1.0/revision/5